# How factorize equations in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, math

I have some long equations, such as:

> θ = -(Tq - Lα + CLβ_1- CLβ_2+ LTδ - Cβ_1 q- Cβ_2 q+ Lαρ + Lαδ - Tqy -
> αρq - αqy + 2αρqy + 2CLβ_1^2 q+ 2CLβ_2^2 q- 2CLβ_1 δ- 3LTβ_1 q- LTβ_2
> q+ Lαβ_1 q+ Lαβ_2 q- 2Lαρδ + 2Cβ_1 qy+ 4CLβ_1 β_2 q+ 2Lαβ_1 ρq)/(2δ +
> 2y + 2Lβ_1- Tq - 2δy - δ^2- y^2- LT + 4β_1^2 qy+ 2β_2^2 qy- 6Lβ_1 δ-
> 2Lβ_2 δ- 2β_1 qy- 2β_2 qy+ 4Lβ_1^2 δ+ 2Lβ_2^2 δ+ Lβ_1^2 q+ Lβ_2^2 q+
> 4LTβ_1 q+ 2LTβ_2 q+ 2Lβ_1 β_2 q- 1)

I want to factorize these equations, How I can do it?
can it be possible for the task in either MATLAB or other software?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the free and open source [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) [Maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io):

which has a `factor` and `ratsimp` command. Ideally you'd use ASCII characters though, so here is just an example of how that would work:

```
expr: x^2 - y^2;
print(factor(expr));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y02syMxN/P8/taKgyEqhIs5IQVehMs7ImqugKDOvRCMtMbkkv0gDJKupaf3/PwA)

Comment: I use `factor`, but it gives me the same equation!

Comment: for example (factor of this equation is as same as it)
**L*alfa - C + 2*C*pii + 2*C*y - C*pii^2 - C*y^2 + alfa*q*y^2 - C*L*T + C*L*beta1 + C*L*beta2 - C*T*q - L*T*pii - L*alfa*p - 2*L*alfa*pii - 2*C*pii*y - T*q*y + L*T*pii^2 + L*T^2*q + L*alfa*pii^2 + T*q*y^2 + alfa*p*q*y + 2*C*L*beta1*pii^2 + 2*C*L*beta2*pii^2 - 2*L*alfa*p*pii^2 + 2*C*beta1*q*y^2 + 2*C*beta2*q*y^2 - 2*alfa*p*q*y^2 - 3*C*L*beta1*pii - 3*C*L*beta2*pii + L*T*alfa*q + L*T*beta1*q + L*T*beta2*q + 3*L*alfa*p*pii - C*beta1*q*y - C*beta2*q*y + 2*C*L*T*beta1*q + 2*C*L*T*beta2*q - 2*L*T*alfa*p*q - L*alfa*beta1*p*q - L*alfa*beta2*p*q**

Comment: This means `factor` is unable to factor your expression any further. (Use backticks to format code.)

Answer (score 0):

First up: MATLAB can't handle Greek letters, so you'll have to use different variable names.
Yes, you can factor this with MATLAB, provided you have the Symbolic Toolbox. Use `factor()`, check [its documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/factor.html) for examples on usage.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for long equations!

Comment: @Alexander define "doesn't work"? Does it error? Does it give incorrect results, does it make your computer explode ...? I presume you face the same issue as in flawr's solution, namely that your function apparently cannot be factorised any further. Did you properly declare all your variables as numeric or symbolic variables, as the docs show?

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial as written by flawr is irreducible, according to Maxima.  Perhaps what you mean by "factor" is something else.

Answer (score 0):

% Factor
f = factor(200)
% Multiply the elements of f to reproduce the input value.

prod(f)
factor(x^3 - y^3)
factor(x^2 - y^2)